# Alternator droop characteristics

Tags: power, alternator

Two synchronous generators operating in parallel supply a total load of 200 MW. The ratings of the machines 1 and 2 are 100 MW and 200 MW. Machines 1 and 2 have governor droop characteristic of 4% and 3% respectively, from no load to full load. 
Assume that at full load, machines run at rated speed and the system frequency is 50 Hz. Calculate the load taken by each machine and the operating frequency

[image: my answer]

Comment: Welcome to EE SE! Is this a homework? Edit your question by showing your approach in solving the problems. Homework questions without effort will get closed.

Comment: What have you attempted so far? People will help by correcting your efforts instead of just handing out a solution...

Comment: No, your answer is incorrect. It would help us immensely if you would enter your work directly into your question, rather than making us squint at a fuzzy photograph with messy handwriting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that "governor droop" means that the frequency increases linearly from 50 Hz by the given percentage as the load drops from the rated power down to zero. Therefore, we need to find the power distribution between the two generators that results in the same percentage of frequency rise for the given total load.

Therefore, we can forget about what the actual frequency is and simply write:

$$f_1 = 4\% \cdot (1 - \frac{P_1}{100\text{ MW}})$$
$$f_2 = 3\% \cdot (1 - \frac{P_2}{200\text{ MW}})$$

where \$f_1\$ and \$f_2\$ represent the percentage change, rather than the actual frequency.

Then, as you have noted, the requirements are \$f_1 = f_2\$ and \$P_1 + P_2 = 200\text{ MW}\$.

This should allow you to come up with the correct answer.